# How can I display data in database in view?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have following tables in my database:

1.Register table:
    `user_id`,`username`,`password`,`email`,`Fname`,`Lname`

2.Tbl_category:`cat_id`

3.Tbl_events:
     `user_id(reference to register table)`,`cat_id(reference to    tbl_category)`,`event_title`,`event_desc`,`event_charge`,`event_venue`.

In my model event_model:

```
function get_event_details() {
    $this -> db -> order_by('event_id', 'desc');
    $query = $this -> db -> get('tbl_events');
    return $query -> result();
}
```

In my controller Home:

```
function get_event_details() {
     $this -> load -> model('event_model');
     $query = $this -> event_model -> get_event_details();
     foreach($query as $ca_id): 
         $c = $ca_id -> cat_id;
     endforeach;

     if ($c = 1) {
         $this -> load -> view('InformationalTechnology');
     }

     if ($c = 1) {
         $this -> load -> view('Entertainment');
     }

     if ($c = 1) {

         $this -> load -> view('Research');
     }

     if ($c = 1) {

         $this -> load -> view('Sports');
     }

 }
```

The page ie View is not being displayed on the basis of $c.I am not getting the exact point where should my correct my code.Please suggest me the best way.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison. Didn't look at the rest.

Comment: What wesley said... also, what's with the crazy spacing $this - > load - > view ?

Comment: == also doesnt worked...

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you want to display specific view depending on the value of `cat_id`. but i can see that you have compared the value of `$c` only with `1`

- secondly as your for loop ends before the view is being loaded you will get the view of the last cat_id.
- and you need to use `==` instead of `=` for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `SWITCH` in your code.